# Colour Blindness Filters

Tags: accessibility

Greetings Friends,

Is there a standard set of downloadable styles that I can overlay on my graphics to simulate the various types of colour-blindness? Ideally for Photoshop or Fireworks.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Comment: +1 because I found your link helpful, but you got a down vote for some reason, possibly for posting it with no explanation (?), but that wouldn't make sense because there was no comment to suggest that. :)

Comment: Thx Chris. It's my joy to know that at least one person found the link helpful. By the way, that link is awesome IMHO. It allows you to simulate different color blindness and export to schemes for GIMP, Photoshop, Inkscape, Corel, Illustrator, CSS...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article which discusses this issue and has a few options:

http://css-tricks.com/accessibility-basics-testing-your-page-for-color-blindness/

**EDIT**

What version of Photoshop do you use? CS4 and CS5 include [a preview for two types of colour blindness](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WS151986BD-6D68-4880-9123-CC0D8B7033F5.html#WS473A333A-7F61-4aba-8F67-5553208E349C) in the "View" menu, under the "Proof Setup" menu item…